# Send a single byte net.Conn Go

Tags: go

I've got a Go TCP server which accepts connections, I'd like to echo the messages back 1 byte at a time, I can't see a way to get net.Conn to send a single byte using net.Conn.Write

`c.Write([]byte(b))
cannot convert b (type byte) to type []byte`

`c.Write(b)
cannot use b (type byte) as type []byte in argument to c.Write`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

an `io.Writer` always accepts a `[]byte` as the argument. Use a 1 byte long byte slice. What you tried (`[]byte(b)`) was to convert a single byte to a byte slice. Instead, create a one-element byte slice with `b` as the only element:

```
n, err := c.Write([]byte{b})
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `b[i:i+1]` to create a one byte slice:

```
s := "Hello world!"
b := []byte(s)

for i:=0; i<len(s); i++ {
    c.Write(b[i:i+1])
}
```

Comment: Why did I get a -1 for this? Please add a comment and explain!